# Recovering files from Windows HDD using Ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery

My windows 7 laptop crashed and won't reboot. So I made a bootable USB with Ubuntu on it, followed all the instructions to try and recover my files from my HDD but I can't see any of my files in the file manager. There is a 'XXXGB' option of device and a 'system' option and both seem to open ok (no messages about mounting errors) but my files just aren't there.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to do something in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your Windows partitions aren't in /etc/fstab, you should try:

```
mkdir /media/windows
mount /dev/sdxY /media/windows
```

Where x is the disk letter and Y the partition number.
Repeat the mount command for every windows partition and you'll be able to access your windows partitions in:

```
/media/windows
```

Comment: Thanks. So I'm new to all this... do I press enter after typing the first line? And where do I find the disk letter and partition number?

Comment: you can use either gparted (GUI) or `sudo fdisk -l` to list partitions

Comment: @KateRobertson Of course you should press enter. `lsblk` will give you the list of disk and partitions.

Comment: @KateRobertson Good luck, don't forget to inform us about your progress ;)

Comment: When I type mkdir /media/windows I get an error: mkdir: cannot create directory '/media/Windows': Permission denied

Comment: @KateRobertson This is strange because you are supposed to be root while booting from a key... Try `sudo mkdir /media/Windows`.

Comment: That worked @Kotshi but the next step isn't working. I ran GParted and there's errors on sda1, sda2, sda4 and sda5. 'Unable to read the contents of this file system'

Comment: @KateRobertson What do you get with `lsblk` ?

Comment: Can I post a picture in here?

Comment: I don't now, maybe a link?

Comment: @KateRobertson Or else edit your question to add it.

Comment: Sorry, had to pop out. Pic is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ibg-1BeltNQUhxaGZlRTRXU2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KateRobertson Okay, sda1 looks like a windows boot loader, sda2 is an 273Go unmounted partition, sda3 looks like some windows crap, sda4 is a 22Go mounted partition so you can access it through /media/windows. I don't know  why sda5 is mounted on /media/ubuntu/SomethingOutOfTheScreen, did you do a complete ubuntu installation?
Anyway, try `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/windows` datas may be on it.

Comment: I used the first option on startup which was to use Ubuntu without installing it. I've tried that and it doesn't seem to be doing anything, pressed enter but the root@ line hasn't reappeared. Does that mean it's still processing?

Comment: @KateRobertson Ho, I didn't notice the graphical interface in the backgound, so obviously you did, let's just hope no datas were on that partition. Did you try `mount /dev/sda2 /media/windows` ?

Comment: Sorry, bit confused now, what have I done? I haven't installed Ubuntu, just selected first option to use without installing. Tried the mount etc and nothing seems to be happening

Comment: Can I see what lslbk looks like now?

Comment: It looks exactly the same. Like I said nothing seemed to happen, the terminal seemed to freeze.

Comment: Ho, then press **ctrl+v**

Comment: Was mount the last command you typed?

Comment: I typed the mount command and nothing happened, I closed the terminal and tried again, still nothing. I'm a new terminal I've done lsblk and now the mount again and still nothing. Pressed ctrl+V and still nothing

Comment: Oups, ctrl+c sorry.

Comment: try `udisks --mount /dev/sda2`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-ibg-1BeltNdGZyenVrRTBFd3M

Comment: `apt-get update` then `apt-get install usdisks` again maybe?

Comment: Nothing is working, I think it's time to give up and take it to the computer repair shop! Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Ho, this is sad to abandon and waste money like this...